# Spotify Web API (Connect)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, spotify

Is there a way to watch for the end of the currently playing song?

If not (which I dont think there is at the moment), what would be a good method to building your own method for watching for the end of a song to fire events (i.e. play the next song in a local queue)?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to build a work around for this using some of the ideas below and now I have a working slack jukebox thats spotify powered

https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/670nce/spotify_powered_slack_jukebox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify doesn't support any sort of webhook/notification system currently. We kind of hacked this together by ["scrobble" spotify](https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/playlists/scrobble-to-last-fm/) to last.fm, start a timer for the length of the song, and periodically checking the [user.getRecentTracks](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks) method which will return a nowPlaying property.

Starting timer for the length of the song itself *could* be enough, but if you skip a track, you'll have issues. So pinging every few seconds is a safe bet.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. pinging the active song every 1000-2000 ms to determine if the song is almost over.  Do you think the spotify API response time would be an issue?

Comment: It might be. You could utilize a flag to prevent it from stepping on itself

Comment: I am relatively new to this sort of thing...

Could you explain what you mean by flag?

Comment: Essentially it would be a way of preventing a request from running until the previous one competed:

function req() {
    request.get('https://last.fm/users.getRecentTracks', req); // if you want it to run immediately after one completes
    request.get('https://last.fm/', () => {
        setTimeout(req, 1500); // change to whatever ms
    })
}

req();